# Readonly attributes/keys with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I would like to know if there is anyway to make an attribute key readonly. Meaning that it can only be assigned when the object is being created

**UPDATE**: I want to be able to use something like update_attributes, and be safe that that method will only update the key that can be overwritten. For example if I have

```
class User 
    include MongoMapper::Document

    key :firstName, String, :required => true
    key :lastName,  String, :required => true
    key :username,  String, :required => true, :unique => true, :readonly => true
    key :password,  String, :required => true

end
```

(The readonly validation is pseudo-code, I would like something like that to exist)

Then I would expect the following code to raise an error or fail

```
user = User.find_by_username("foo")
user.update_attributes({:username => "bar"})
puts "You cannot change the username" unless user.valid?
```

I also would like something like this, but is a separate thing

```
user.update_attributes({:unwantedKey => "fail!"})
puts "You cannot add keys that are not in the User scheme" unless user.valid?
```

Comment: you as the programmer are responsible when something is assigned or not. Or do you mean you want to avoid a key being changed through params? Then you can use `attr_accessbile :key_x`

Comment: @three I updated the question with an example.

Comment: @GuidoMB I'm quite confused about why you want the behavior you are asking for. It smells like the wrong solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve. Can you provide some more motivation?

Comment: @PlasticChicken I'm exposing CRUD operations using Sinatra over a User entity. In the update method the consumers of the API cant PUT any update on the user entity except for the username field. That is why I'm using the update_attributes method because I don't want to manually update each change. But I don't want the username field to be changed

Answer (score 1):

I would revisit your requirement that you need to do this with validations rather than using custom controller filtering or `attr_accessible` to control [accessibilty](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/accessible.html).

If validations really are the correct solution, rolling your own like [three suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145819/readonly-attributes-keys-with-mongomapper#answer-9151165) is a good idea, here's some identity-map-safe code to check against the database:

```
validate :username_unchanged, :only_existing_keys, :on => :update

def db_version
  # drop to the driver to get around the identity map
  # (identity map is off by default)
  collection.find_one(:_id => self.id)
end

def username_unchanged
  unless username == db_version['username']
    errors.add(:username, 'cannot be changed')
  end
end

def only_existing_keys
  extra_keys = to_mongo.keys - db_version.keys
  unless extra_keys.size == 0
    errors.add(:base, 'You cannot add keys to the schema')
  end
end
```

But watch out! **MongoMapper does not store keys whose value is `nil`**.  That's going to foil the `only_existing_keys` method above, so you may have to store an array of valid keys somewhere.

Hopefully that's a sufficient starting point.

Answer (score 0):

you can introduce a custom validation like this:

```
before_update :check_username
validate :read_only

def check_username
  @temp_username = self.username
end

def read_only
  false if self.username != self.temp_username
end
```

not sure if this will work but you have callbacks and validation and you can use both to make sure nothing is changed.

http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/callbacks.html
http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/validations.html